# Write a recursive function matching_bracket(string, idx) to find the index of the close bracket matching the open bracket at string[idx]

Tags: python, parentheses

While there are many questions on stackoverflow to check if the string is balanced, what I need is to find the index of the closing bracket of `string[idx]`. For example:

```
>>> matching_bracket('([])', 0)
3

>>> matching_bracket('([])', 1)
2
```

There are 3 conditions that will return `-1`:

1. the closing bracket is not of the same type
2. the nested brackets are not matched [IMPORTANT]
3. there are no more brackets available

Here is what I have so far:

```
def matching_bracket(string, idx):
  open_tup = ("(", "{", "<", "[")
  close_tup = (")", "}", ">", "]")
  chosen = string[idx]
  b_index = open_tup.index(chosen)
  n = len(string) - 1
  if string[idx + 1] in open_tup: # Case 1: Check if nested brackets match
    return matching_bracket(string, idx + 1)
  elif string[n] != close_tup[b_index]: # Case 2: Closing bracket not the same
    return matching_bracket(string[0 : n], idx)
  elif len(string) == 1: # Case 3: No more available brackets
    return -1
  else:
    return n
```

While I am running a recursive function to check if the nested brackets are closed as well, I am having difficulty getting the correct output as I end up returning the index of the closing bracket that is nested instead. See below:

```
>>> matching_bracket('([])', 0)
2
```

How should I modify my code?

Comment: Can the input index be negative as well?

Comment: No it can't! @SayandipDutta

Answer (score 0):

In above code, in first if condition your are checking whether the next bracket is of type open. if it is you are calling matching_bracket with next bracket index. and losing the actual open bracket index for which you want close bracket index. 
Checkout following solution using :

```
def matching_bracket(string, idx):
    open_tup = ("(", "{", "<", "[")
    close_tup = (")", "}", ">", "]")

    dict_brackets = {"{": "}", "(": ")", "<": ">", "[": "]"}
    stack = []
    if string[idx] in close_tup or idx >= len(string):
        return -1
    stack.append(string[idx])
    for t in range(idx + 1, len(string)):
        if string[t] in open_tup:
            stack.append(string[t])
        else:
            if string[t] != dict_brackets.get(stack.pop()):
                return -1
            elif len(stack) == 0:
                return t
    return -1
```

Comment: I need to solve this by recursion though, instead of using a stack!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little convoluted, but should do:

```
def matching_bracket(string, idx):
    bracket_dict = {'[':']', '(':')', '{':'}', '<':'>'}
    # Actual recursive function
    def inner_func(ix_open, ix_close):
        if string[ix_close] == bracket_dict[string[ix_open]]:
            return ix_open, ix_close
        else:
            if ix_close + 1 == len(string) - 1:
                return ix_open, -1
            else:
                return inner_func(ix_open+1, ix_close+1)
    if idx == len(string) - 1:
        return -1
    elif string[idx + 1] == bracket_dict[string[idx]]:
        return idx + 1
    elif idx == len(string) - 2:
        return -1
    else:
        ix_open, ix_close = idx+2, idx+1
        while ix_open != idx and ix_close != -1:
            ix_open, ix_close = ix_open - 1, ix_close + 1
            ix_open, ix_close = inner_func(ix_open, ix_close)
        return ix_close
```

PS: Wrote down the solution way back, forgot to post :p

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to match open delimiters and close them with corresponding delimiters, take a look at this [library](https://github.com/TotallyNotChase/Smart-Delimiter-Predictor) I made, perhaps the algorithm can help you, though it is in `java`.

Here's how it works-

- First the class needs to know which opening delimiter matches which closing delimiter - you can use a dictionary for this in python

```py
delim_dict = {}
delim_dict['('] = ')'
.....
```

- Now if you're *only* interested in checking whether the **closing** and **opening** delimiters don't match - take a look at [this function](https://github.com/TotallyNotChase/Smart-Delimiter-Predictor/blob/1912fd42aecc96766800074e83f72665a8428ce1/src/com/github/chase/smartdelimiter/SmartDelimiterPredictor.java#L46).
  Simply put, you have to count the number of each **closing delimiter** and **open delimiter**, reverse iterating the string from backwards. Whenever you see the, if the counts don't match, you know the delimiters are also not matched
- Now if you want to find the *index* of your desired delimiter - take a look at [this function](https://github.com/TotallyNotChase/Smart-Delimiter-Predictor/blob/1912fd42aecc96766800074e83f72665a8428ce1/src/com/github/chase/smartdelimiter/SmartDelimiterPredictor.java#L84)
  It's designed to find the *mathematical function* in an expression, given its closing delimiter, but you can modify it to match your usecase. Since you want to find a *closing delimiter*, given *opening delimiter*, you should be iterating the expression in normal order, instead of reverse

```py
# opening_delim is given as parameter
closing_delim = get_corresponding_delimiter(opening_delim)
closing_delim_count, opening_delim_count = 0, 0
i = 0
for item in expression:
    if expression[i] == opening_delim:
        opening_delim_count += 1
    elif expression[i] == closing_delim:
        closing_delim_count+= 1
    if opening_delim_count == closing_delim_count:
        return i
    i += 1
```

Of course, this code is only for the first index's delimiter and it *also* assumes the delimiters are matched correctly